# how to send json data to server in cordova android

Tags: json, cordova

hi frnd form last 2 days i am trying to send JSON data to server but is not working i am posting my js file and check if any error. and i am try to send json data by using xmlHttprequest. and if any other function and any change i have to do then plz tell me. i am developing cordova project in eclipse.and if any other thing and any file also have to change then tell me
            this is my js file and on click registration button i am calling this method.

```
        function get() {
            alert("function is called");
             var name_field_value=document.getElementById("name_field").value;
            var email_field_value=document.getElementById("email_field").value;
            var password_field_value=document.getElementById("password_field").value;
            var phone_field_value=document.getElementById("phone_field").value;

             var JSONdata= {
                    "name": name_field_value,
                    "mobile_number": phone_field_value,
                    "email": email_field_value,
                    "password": password_field_value
                }
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open("POST", "http://www.jiyonatural.com/AccountManagements/insert_new_user", true);
                request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (request.readyState == 4) {
                        alert(request.status);//this alert is working and getting 0 status
                        if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
                            // -> request.responseText <- is a result
                            /*var tweets = JSON.parse(request.responseText);*/
                            alert(request.responseText);//this alert is not working// 
                            //if i make other alert then it works
                        }else{
                            alert("function is called3");}
                    }
                }
                request.send(JSON.stringify(JSONdata));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your question is incomplete.
In my experience the error probably lies in server code friend.

And you should use ajax method in jquery for communication with server.its easier than XMLhttpRequest.